# Unity Resources.Load<Sprite> vs as Sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources, load, sprite, renderer

I've tried to change the image of my object with this code (used **as Sprite** cast):

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole") as Sprite;
```

It did not work, however this worked (used **<Sprite>**):

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole");
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Do you have multiple files in your project named "Hole"? The one command specifies an asset type to search for, but the other does not. Depending on your file structure, they might be looking up different results because of that.

Answer (score 4):

FunctionR's answer is probably the more common answer, and I may just be wrong here, but I believe the difference between `Load()` and `Load<T>()` is that `Load<T>()` checks for meta-data. "Hole" is not a `Sprite`, it's an image file. `Load()` finds that image file and loads it as it's default type for the file type, in this case `Texture2D`.

In other words, you can't use `as Sprite` because you cannot `cast` a `Texture2D` to a `Sprite`. You CAN, however, use

```
Texture2D texure = Resources.Load("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole");
Rect rect        = {whatever};
Vector2 pivot    = {whatever};

Sprite.Create(texture, rect, pivot);
```

but this requires you to know the size of the `Sprite` you were trying to load.

In summary, `Load()` treats it based solely on the file type you're loading, `Load<T>()` includes metadata.

Answer (score 3):

```
Resources.Load("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole") as Sprite;
```

You have another "Hole" in your Resources folder. This *other-Hole* is not a `Sprite`. Therefore when you use `as Sprite` it simply can't be casted to one and won't throw an exception (on that line) because:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

---

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole");
```

In the working code you specify which file you want, the `Sprite`, so it finds the correct one.

Comment: In the Windows Explorer I have one file called **Hole.png**, and an other called **Hole.png.meta** if I **Debug.Log(Resources.Load<Sprite>("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole"));** then it's a **Sprite** and if I **Debug.Log((Resources.Load("GameObjects/Tiles/Hole")));** then it's a **Texture2D**.. So the **.meta** file is a Texture2D file? In the Unity Project explorer however I have only one Resource file called Hole.